# Grant Multiple ROLE Security.yml

Tags: symfony

I want that the user with the role ROLE_USER_1 or ROLE_USER_2 is getting to `^/(de|en)/secured/account/`. But what I **don't** want that e.g. a user with ROLE_USER_2 can go to `^/(de|en)/secured/account/profile` or any other action. User with the role ROLE_USER_2 can only go to `^/(de|en)/secured/account/`.

What is wrong with my security.yml:

```
    role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
       ROLE_USER_B2B:    ROLE_USER_B2B_INACTIVE  
    access_control:
       - { path: ^/(en|de)/secured/account/$, roles: [ROLE_USER_B2B_INACTIVE, ROLE_USER_B2B] }
       - { path: ^/(en|de)/secured/account/*, roles: ROLE_USER_B2B }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer, what is working! Just had to switch the first `roles`! A little bit stupid. And I uncomment the role hierachy with `ROLE_USER_B2B`.

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
access_control:
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/secured/b2b/account/$, roles: [ROLE_USER_B2B, ROLE_USER_B2B_INACTIVE] }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/secured/b2b/account/*, roles: ROLE_USER_B2B }
```